# When I use a function to query an InputStream and then return it, it automatically closed

Tags: android, inputstream

```
public InputStream executeQuery(String query) throws IOException {
        if(!networkTest()){
            return null;
        }
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;


        URL url = new URL(query);
        httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());



        if (httpURLConnection != null) {
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return in;

    }
```

the code return a closed input stream but when inside this function, the input stream is not closed. Why?

Comment: `httpURLConnection.disconnect()` will close the stream. Moreover you better change `String query` to `String url`. And that url is not querying an input stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the data from the input stream before disconnecting the connection, as it will close the associated streams.

You can use this code to read the response before closing the connection.

```
public String streamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```